# How to detect permission dialog is denied by user

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, permissions

I am implementing take pictures from galley in my app, for which I am adding storage permission.
And I am requesting the permission  from user using permission_handler package. And it is working perfectly in Android because it manages user state like permanently denied etc.
But the main issue in the iOS in which either user deny or allow always shows user granted permission(Means always providing the status == granted)

Please help if someone have same issue or I am doing anything wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: you can read carefully https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler

Answer (score 1):

Add `permission_handler: ^6.1.1` to you pubspec file

import it

```
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
```

in you landing page or `main.dart` try calling this bellow functoin

```
bool storagePer = false;
    void storageCheck() async {
      var status = await Permission.storage.status;
      if (!status.isGranted) {
        await Permission.storage.request();
        storagePer = true;
        print('per: $storagePer');
      }
    }
```

To check if you have permission or not, use `status.isGranted`  if it return true => permissionGranted else denied

to request permition use this `await Permission.storage.request();`

Comment: yes, you are right "Aditya kontikal", I am using it the same way. And it is working fine for android but for iOS giving the only status.isGranted(either user deny or allow the permission)

Comment: Thank you, I found the solution, in iOS instead of storage permission I changed it to photos: - 
  if (Platform.isIOS) {
      status = await Permission.photos.request();
    } else if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      status = await Permission.storage.request();
    }